# Text spacing between words not the same in <p> tag

Tags: html, css

I have an annoying HTML/CSS issue. I have a `<p>` tag with text between it. The `<p>` tag is quite small, basically the size of an iPhone screen. Now when that `<p>` tag with the text inside is displayed, the some of the text have unwanted spaces between them:

```
Example:

My text has    irregular spacing
It     is    kinda annoying for 
me, can anyone please assist me.
```

Note: I did try using

```
text-align: justify; and
word-spacing: 3px;
```

but it does not help
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of

```
text-align: justify;
```

If you change it to

```
text-align: left;
```

then it'll be gone.

Comment: thanks, it works, only problem is that the text is not justified anymore. I want the text to be in a square block(aligned equally left and right) but I don't want the middle spacing issue...How do I get best of both worlds?

Comment: Then you have to keep it justified and to avoid the unwanted spaces you may keep the width of your paragraph a little small, so it won't stretch the lines.

Comment: ok thanks, will do so.I will just use my discretion. There is one part where the text-align left works better even though it does not justify

Comment: I really find it inspiring that experienced guys like yourself are willing to help novices like me on this forum. keep it up!

Comment: Thanks but learning never ends and this site is a good place to learn and contribute. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the best of both worlds because `text-align:justify;` **is** causing this. It's part of the game. I know it might be annoying when you have a sentence of 3 words that suddenly have lot more space between the words...but that's what makes justify..justify!

Answer (score 1):

Using justify will give just the result you got.
Have you tried

```
{text-align:left;}
```

Comment: thanks, it works, only problem is that the text is not justified anymore. I want the text to be in a square block(aligned equally left and right) but I don't want the middle spacing issue...How do I get best of both worlds?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following css:

```
text-align: justify;
```

Comment: nope, it does not work... I just stated that I tried using justified to see if it helps, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the word-spacing setting. If this is not sufficient, post a complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I never used the word spacing as part of my script, I just mentioned it to say that i tried using it to solve the issue, that way someone won't suggest it in an answer possibly